# I need to use the output (its value) of one mySQL query in another

Tags: php, mysql, variables, sql-update, subquery

I have trouble using the output of one query as a value in another. The thing is I need to get the price of one product (which is successfully accomplished) using the following query:

```sql
SELECT Cena FROM Proizvod WHERE ProzivodID = $PID
```

$PID is a PHP variable and this query works just fine. The problem comes when I want to subtract the price of the product from the buyer's balance.
I tried to do that with the following query:

```sql
UPDATE Kupuvac SET Saldo = Saldo - ".$cena." WHERE KupuvacID=$KID
```

$cena is a PHP variable, the value of which is the first query.

The second query doesn't work at all, it doesn't return an error message, but it doesn't change he buyer's balance.

---

*A short dictionary if someone needs it:   `Cena - Price`;   `Proizvod - Product`;   `Kupuvac - Buyer`;   `Saldo - Balance`.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you checking the second query for errors and can you check the value of the affected rows?  What mysql api are you using (mysql_, mysqli, PDO)?  Thanks

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin which is integrated in xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do your `UPDATE` operation in one statement:

```
UPDATE Kupuvac a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT Cena FROM Proizvod WHERE ProzivodID = $PID
) b
SET a.Saldo = a.Saldo - b.Cena
WHERE a.KupuvacID = $KID
```

Comment: It returns error: #1054 - Unknown column 'ProizvodID' in 'where clause'

Comment: @AndrewAlbertPetrovsky, Fixed. I had thought it was just a typo.

Comment: Great, but if the other answer had already worked for you, you should have not unaccepted it!

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just combine these into one query?

```sql
UPDATE Kupuvac 
SET Saldo = Saldo - (SELECT Cena FROM Proizvod WHERE ProzivodID = $PID) 
WHERE KupuvacID = $KID
```

Comment: Notice that if there is no row (product) to match the `ProzivodID = $PID` condition, the `Saldo` will be set to `NULL`, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You are right, but in this case the product is chosen from a drop-down menu, so there will always be a row to mach the ID. Anyway, a good remark, it will come in handy in the further development of the project. Thank you.